# How to skip an activity and close app

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have 3 activities with sequence A->B->C.
A is the Login Activity.
B is the Welcome Activity
Now When I start the app, I'm at Screen B, because I was logged in.
Now when I press back it takes me to Screen A, that I dont't want.I want to close my app after back press but with condition When I press logged out on Screen B, then I should be at Screen A.How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this many ways . one simple solution is .

1. Finish activity A when moving to B , So now you press Back button on B the app will close.

   ```
   startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, A.class));
   finish();
   ```
2. On Logout launch the activity A.

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
   // Flag are optional if you have multiple activities in stack 
   //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
   startActivity(intent);
   finish();
   ```